# Find which categorical parameters have correlation with a given property

Tags: correlation, modeling, biostatistics

I am a molecular biologist, so I apologize in advance, if the question is too basic. Example described below is for simplicity (I have a similar situation with my data to the one I describe below)

I have a set of test subjects, each test subject has a unique combination of the following parameters:

1) age (integer number from 10 to 70)
2) gender (male, female)
3) shoe size (integer numbers from 32 to 45)
4) favourite character on game of thrones (John Snow, Cercei, Tyrion, Oberyn, Tywin)
5) country of origin (all 179 countries)
6) level of education (koindergarden, primary school, secondary school, Bsc, Msc, phD)

note

1) all the parameters are categorical, i.e. age can be only integer numbers between 10 and 70, it cant be 11,7839393

2) I have one observation for ALL possible combinations (even when they dont make sense), e.g. age 10, education - phD, shoe size 45

Now I need to find which parameters are somehow correlated with level of intelligence and which aren't and are there parameters which when combined have an effect. I for example understand that (3) shoe size and 4) favourite character on game of thrones) dont really have an effect, while age and level of education should obviously demonstrate such correlation. Also given poor education for women in some countries I also expect women to have lower level of intellect but only when gender is combined with country of origin.

What method would you recommend for such analysis? I am an advanced R user.

Comment: Its not true that all your parameters are categorical. Age is perfectly fine, real-valued variable (even if you only have integers). Shoe size, and level of education are ordinal. Only Gender, GOT character, and Country of Origin are categorical.

Comment: Also, how can you have an observation from a nonsensical combination (i.e, the large-footed genius child)

Comment: This is just an example. I have some other data I acquired, but I did not want to describe it here not to confuse people. Perhaps you can just answer my question making assumption, that indeed all combinations are possible and all the data is categorical. E.g. age can only be 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50

Comment: Age being limited to integers is still not categorical. Its ordinal.